# Why are there Arrays in JavaScript? Don't Objects suffice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm re-learning JavaScript at the moment.

My tutor told me today that in JavaScript, "everything is an object". In fact, using a `for`-`in` loop, you can iterate over an object's properties just like you can over an array's elements.

I now have (yet another) naive question: If everything in JavaScript is an `Object`, why do people "bother" using `Array`s?

My first guess is there must be methods on `Array` that aren't available on `Object` (which a quick and superficial glance at MDN seems to confirm), and `Array`s can be indexed (i.e. `myArray[i]`) (and have a `length`). But is that the whole story? Or is there some performance gain to be had by using the built-in `Array` (object) data type?

Comment: How would you model a collection of objects without arrays?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole story. Isn't that enough reason for an Array data type?

Comment: I'm a bit sleep-deprived by now, but couldn't you create a chain? `myObject.nextObject = {}` Although I can see that that would be a bit awkward... :)

Comment: (the performance gain can be neglected, todays engines optimise indexed access on normal objects as well; and they surely would even more if objects were designed to be used as arrays everywhere)

Comment: That is a linked list (not an array) @Christian

Comment: @Tuvia Point taken. I think I got the idea because of expando properties: `myObject.one = {}; myObject.two = {}; // etc.` It just "feels" a lot like an array - to a beginner anyway. :)

Comment: You can iterate an array **by order** but not object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, an `Array` is an `Object`, but an `Object` **is not** an `Array`. The same is true for other types as well, such as `Date`, `RegExp` and so on.

You could strip the language of many native features and *still* have the exact same solution scope boundaries (you could solve the exact same set of problems), but you'd repeat yourself over and over implementing very basic objects. Additionally, different code bases would use different implementations of these types and you'd loose compatibility and interoperability.

Having certain types natively implemented makes using the language easier, more robust, more explicit *and* more performant.

On top of all that, languages as a whole (and JavaScript in particular) strive to conform to well known practices - it makes adopting the language easier and porting existing code simpler and faster.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays **are** an object type. (as are functions, object etc).

They have internal counter and push and pop states among other things. And they have many uses (to keep collections of data for one).

If you *really* want to reimplement that *kol hakavod* (go right ahead).

It is a fun project though to try to re-implement a js array on your own.